# Almacenar varias variables (o un array) en un mismo campo (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

¿Alguien me puede decir cual sería la mejor opción para almacenar los siguientes datos?

El usuario (dentro de un formulario) tiene la posibilidad de seleccionar múltiples checkbox (19), y necesito almacenar si están marcados o no (todos ellos) en un solo campo.

Podría usar un Array, pero no sé cómo almacenarlo en la base de datos. Y si pueden, me gustaría ver un ejemplo, ya que en la página ofilical de PHP no acabo de entender el uso.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Almacenar es lo de menos: ¿ también tienes que **buscar** si determinados *checkbox* están o no marcados ?

Comment: Sí, esos datos se usan para generar una página (basada en una plantilla), donde se debe conocer el valor de cada uno de ellos. Estén marcados o no (Será más fácil)

Comment: Cabe destacar que desde la versión `5.7.8`, MySQL soporta un tipo de datos `JSON`, el cual permite guardar verdaderos objetos `JSON`. [Aquí hay una guía sobre su uso](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/) y esta es la [documentación oficial sobre el tipo de datos `JSON`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) en el manual de referencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra posibilidad, es que cuando des a guardar el formulario correspondiente, esos checkbox lleguen como un array en tu controlador PHP y guardarlos como una cadena json. Luego, cuando lo leas de bbdd, lo conviertes otra vez a un array. Los indices que tengas definidos seran los que has chequeado.

si consigues que llegue un array a tu controlador asi:

```
$checks = $_POST['checkboxes'];
```

y al imprimir ese array lo has formado como:

```
[ 
'check1' => true, 
'check4' => true,
'check9' => true
]
```

Entonces podrias convertirlo en json con:

```
$checksEnBBDD = json_encode($checks, true);
```

Cuando vayas a leerlos de bbdd, utilizas json_decode:

```
$checks = json_decode($checkEnBBDD, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para almacenar varias variables en un campo puedes usar xml o json, por ejemplo este script es parte de un evento que llamo para recuperar los datos de una encuesta con su respectivo valor que va de 1 a 5:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn").click(function() {
          var valores = "<xml>";
            $(".pregunta").each(function() {
                valores +='<row><P>'+$(this).prop("id")+'</P>'
                +'<R>'+$(this).find('input[type=radio]:checked').attr('value')+'</R></row>'
             });
        valores = valores+"</xml>";
        document.cookie = "resultados = " + valores;
      });
```

los guardo en una cookie y luego los proceso en php donde guardo todas las respuestas en una campo de valor NVARCHAR(MAX) en formato xml, este archivo lo creo recorriendo cada elemento que tenga la clase "pregunta" con jquery y recupero el valor del atributo.

Esto te pude dar una idea de como hacerlo, si me muestras como esta estructurada tu pagina posiblemente pueda ser mas preciso al orientarte.

Saludos