# Guardar nombres introducidos en input en la misma variable

Tags: php, session, entrada

Estoy practicando las SESSION_START() en php.

Tengo un input donde introducir nombres, y quiero que todos los nombres introducidos se guarden en la misma variable para crear una lista con todos los nombres introducidos. Este es el código..

```
<form action="sesion.php" method="post">
  <label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nombre">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="BEnviar" value="Enviar">
</form>



<?php
    SESSION_START();

$_SESSION['nombre'] = $_POST['nombre'];
$nombre = $_SESSION['nombre'];

echo "<li>$nombre</li>";
?>
```

Gracias!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Almacenar varias variables (o un array) en un mismo campo (MySQL)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203180/almacenar-varias-variables-o-un-array-en-un-mismo-campo-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guardar un array dentro de `$_SESSION['nombre']` de esta forma:

```
session_start();

// Si existe y es un array ingresamos el nuevo nombre:
if (isset($_SESSION['nombre']) ? is_array($_SESSION['nombre']) : false) {
    array_push($_SESSION['nombre'], $_POST['nombre']);
}
else { // si no es un array (o no existe), lo convertimos en array:
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = array($_POST['nombre']);
}
```

Luego puedes mostrar los datos así:

```
foreach($_SESSION['nombre'] as $nombre) {
    echo "<li>".$nombre."</li>";
}
```

Ojalá te sirva.

Comment: Es perfecto JCAguilera, justo lo que necesitaba!

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido, por favor marca la respuesta como correcta. Gracias!